# Servlet Cannot edit record from database

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, edit, record

I have a servlet that should update a record from my database.
There must be something wrong with my code because tomcat shows error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null @package_ergasia.EditProtein.doPost(EditProtein.java:36) which is this line: `int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("i"));`

Here is my Servlet:

```
package package_ergasia;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;    


public class EditProtein extends HttpServlet 
{
    Connection connection;  
    Statement statement;
    ResultSet  resultset;


   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException 
   {     
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Connection connection= null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "ergasia";    
    String user = "root";
    String password = "password";
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String name = request.getParameter("pname");
    String desc = request.getParameter("desc");
    String seq = request.getParameter("seq");  
    int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("i"));


          try { 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, user, password); 

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE protein SET pdb_id=?,proteinName=?,description=?,proteinSequence=? WHERE i=?");
            ps.setString(1, id);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ps.setString(3, desc);
            ps.setString(4, seq);
            ps.setInt(5, i);

            ps.executeUpdate();   
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/InsertProtein");
            view.forward(request, response);                

        } catch (SQLException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


   }
}
```

Here is the jsp with the form where the user can update the data:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/mystyle.css">        
    </head>
    <body>
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
          <form method="post" action="/EditProtein">
              <fieldset style="width: 100px"> 
              <legend>Update protein table</legend>  
          <table border="1">

<% 
int count = 0;    


                if (session.getAttribute("EditData") != null) {
                    ArrayList al1 = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("EditData");
                    Iterator itr = al1.iterator();

                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        count++;


                        ArrayList pList = (ArrayList) itr.next();
%>                              

                    <tr>  
                        <td>pdb_id</td> 
                         <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" font="Verdana" name="id" value="<%=pList.get(0)%>"</td>                       
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Protein Name</td>  
                        <td><input type="text" font="Verdana" name="pname" value="<%=pList.get(1)%>"</td>                          
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Description</td>  
                        <td><input type="text" font="Verdana" name="desc" value="<%=pList.get(2)%>"</td>                          
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Sequence</td>  
                        <td><input type="text" font="Verdana" name="seq" value="<%=pList.get(3)%>"</td>                          
                    </tr> 
                     <tr>  
                        <td>i</td>  
                        <td><input type="number" disabled="disabled" font="Verdana" name="i" value="<%=pList.get(4)%>"</td>                          
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>  
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                    </tr>   
                    <% }} %>

          </table>
            </fieldset>   
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` on this line `Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("i"));` means that a request parameter with the name `i` is not received from the incoming request for some unclear reasons that cannot be imagined from provided code in the question. How do you pass this request parameter? You might have forgotten to pass this parameter or named something different. Please try looking into the other side on.

Comment: As a side note : you cannot declare `Connection`, `Statement` (or `PreparedStatement`) and `ResultSet` as class members. They should be used and closed precisely in a shortest possible scope which is normally the method in which they are to be used (Servlets are thread-unsafe resources and have an application-wide scope. They will all be reused/shared across all the requests).

Comment: Looks like I can't pass any parameter. I added the jsp, which contains the form where the user edits the data. Up to that point it works fine because the form loads the data successfully.

Comment: You have not closed any `<input type="text"/>` elements. This is an invalid HTML mark up. This for example, `<input type="text" font="Verdana" name="pname" value="<%=pList.get(1)%>"` should be changed to `<input type="text" font="Verdana" name="pname" value="<%=pList.get(1)%>"/>`. Look closely at the very end of the tag. Also try looking into the generated HTML on your favourite browser to see, if the HTML code is correctly rendered and you will be able to find out the bugs in your code.

Comment: @Tiny Can't believe it was so simple, I think I need to rest!
Thank you so much! I did what you said and it was able to pass all parameters except those that were disabled. I enabled them and it passed them all. I had them disabled because I want them grayed out so that the user cannot edit them (can't type) but can see them. Since disabled caused so much trouble is there any other way that I can do that?

Comment: I did it with readonly attribute but it can still be clicked.

Comment: Well read-only input fields/elements can still get focused i.e. the cursor can still be positioned inside them. Disabled input fields on the other hand, are not sent/submitted to the server as request parameters hereby they are unavailable on the server and `request.getParameter("paramName");` would then return `null`.

Comment: If the sole purpose of that disabled/read-only input field were to merely display a value which is not supposed to be edited by application users then, you had better choose different elements like `<span>` (inline element), `<div>` (block-level element) (they would not be submitted as request parameters, of course, since they do not have the `name` attribute associated with them) just to show a value ; and a corresponding hidden form field `<input type="hidden" name="i".../>`. The value of the hidden form field would then be available on the server-side as a request parameter.

Comment: As a side note : You are strictly not supposed to rely upon the disabled/readonly property on the client-side as such things can easily be bypassed by users (it is so easy as even a child can do it :)). You should precisely be doing validations on the server-side as well in your real applications (in addition to client-side validations, if at all).

Comment: Dully noted, thanks again Tiny.

Answer (score 1):

here possible error line is

int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("i"));

request.getParameter("i") is not properly set on your previous page.
in this servlet parameter value is get as null,or other then number(like i76 - i is not number).

check your previous page there i is set.

Comment: If the supplied parameter `i` had had a `String` like `i76`, parsing it to an `int` would have caused the exception, `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "i76"`.

Comment: Added my previous page, looks like I can't load any parameter.

Comment: check the previous page parameter name is "i" or not??
just like; 

<input type="text" name="i" value="" id="someId/i">

Answer (score 0):

Check if the parameter i is sent. Becaus if it is not set, request.getParameter("i") will return null, and when you try to convert it to an int you get the error

Comment: Added my previous page, looks like I can't get any parameter.